# Could not execute method for android :onClick

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

hi developers i'm new in learning android development i do an tic tac toe game with Kotlin It work fine but i write a function that make the device play with me but i get this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ticgame, PID: 28043
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5338)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21539)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:819)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5982)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5338) 
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21539) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:819) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5982) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742) 
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:182)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.AutoPaly(MainActivity.kt:132)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.PLayGame(MainActivity.kt:55)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.AutoPaly(MainActivity.kt:149)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.PLayGame(MainActivity.kt:55)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.AutoPaly(MainActivity.kt:149)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.PLayGame(MainActivity.kt:55)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.AutoPaly(MainActivity.kt:149)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.PLayGame(MainActivity.kt:55)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.AutoPaly(MainActivity.kt:149)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.PLayGame(MainActivity.kt:55)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.AutoPaly(MainActivity.kt:149)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.PLayGame(MainActivity.kt:55)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.AutoPaly(MainActivity.kt:149)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.PLayGame(MainActivity.kt:55)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.AutoPaly(MainActivity.kt:149)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.PLayGame(MainActivity.kt:55)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.AutoPaly(MainActivity.kt:149)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.PLayGame(MainActivity.kt:55)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.buClick(MainActivity.kt:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5338) 
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21539) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:819) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5982) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742)
```

Main Activity

```
package com.example.ticgame
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.util.Random
import android.widget.Button


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

}

var activePlayer=1

var player1=ArrayList<Int>()

var player2=ArrayList<Int>()

var Draw:Int=0
```

Click Function

```
fun buClick(View:View) {
    val BuSelected= View as  Button
    var CellId=0

    when(BuSelected.id){
        R.id.button1-> CellId = 1
        R.id.button2-> CellId = 2
        R.id.button3-> CellId = 3
        R.id.button4-> CellId = 4
        R.id.button5-> CellId = 5
        R.id.button6-> CellId = 6
        R.id.button7-> CellId = 7
        R.id.button8-> CellId = 8
        R.id.button9-> CellId = 9
    }
     Log.d("buCliked",BuSelected.id.toString())
      Log.d("buCliked", CellId.toString())
    PLayGame(CellId,BuSelected)

}
```

Play Game Function

```
fun PLayGame(CellId:Int,BuSelected:Button ) {
    
    
 if (activePlayer==1){
     Toast.makeText(this,"Player 1 played X",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
     BuSelected.text="X"
     BuSelected.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Blue)
     player1.add(CellId)
     AutoPlay()
     Draw++
     activePlayer=2
 }else {
     Toast.makeText(this,"Player 2 played O",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
     BuSelected.text="O"
     BuSelected.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Green)
     player2.add(CellId)
     Draw++
     activePlayer=1
 }
    BuSelected.isEnabled=false //No one can't Click on button againe
    CheckWinner(BuSelected)
}
```

Check Winner Function

```
fun CheckWinner(BuSelected:Button ){
    var Winner:Int=-1
    //row 1
    if(player1.contains(1) && player1.contains(2) && player1.contains(3)){ Winner=1 }
    else if(player2.contains(1) && player2.contains(2) && player2.contains(3)){ Winner=2}


    //row 2
    if(player1.contains(4) && player1.contains(5) && player1.contains(6)){ Winner=1 }
    else if(player2.contains(4) && player2.contains(5) && player2.contains(6)){Winner=2}


    //row 3
    if(player1.contains(7) && player1.contains(8) && player1.contains(8)){ Winner=1 }
    else if(player2.contains(7) && player2.contains(8) && player2.contains(9)){Winner=2}


    /////////////////////////////colums////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //colum 1
    if(player1.contains(1) && player1.contains(4) && player1.contains(7)){ Winner=1 }
    else if(player2.contains(1) && player2.contains(4) && player2.contains(7)){ Winner=2}


    //colum 2
    if(player1.contains(2) && player1.contains(5) && player1.contains(8)){ Winner=1 }
    else if(player2.contains(2) && player2.contains(5) && player2.contains(8)){Winner=2}


    //colum 3
    if(player1.contains(3) && player1.contains(6) && player1.contains(9)){ Winner=1 }
    else if(player2.contains(3) && player2.contains(6) && player2.contains(9)){Winner=2}

  ////////////////////////////////digonale//////////////////////////////////////

    // main digonale
    if(player1.contains(1) && player1.contains(5) && player1.contains(9)){ Winner=1 }
    else if(player2.contains(1) && player2.contains(5) && player2.contains(9)){Winner=2}

    //non-main digonale
    if(player1.contains(3) && player1.contains(5) && player1.contains(7)){ Winner=1 }
    else if(player2.contains(3) && player2.contains(5) && player2.contains(7)){Winner=2}

    //Check Winner
    if (Winner==1){ Toast.makeText(this,"Player 1 is Winner",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }

    else if(Winner==2){ Toast.makeText(this,"Player 2 is Winner",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }

    else if(Draw==9){Toast.makeText(this," Draw ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()}
}
```

AutoPlay function
when i write this function and run the app the and press any button in the game error occur

```
fun AutoPlay(){

    var emptyCells= ArrayList<Int>()

    for(cellId in 1..9 ) {
        if ( !(player1.contains(cellId) || player2.contains(cellId)) ){
            emptyCells.add(cellId)
        }
    }

    val r= Random()
    var randIndex=r.nextInt(emptyCells.size)
    var cellId=emptyCells[randIndex]

    val buSelected : Button?

    buSelected=when(cellId){
        1-> {button1}
        2-> {button2}
        3-> {button3}
        4-> {button4}
        5-> {button5}
        6-> {button6}
        7-> {button7}
        8-> {button8}
        9-> {button9}
        else-> {button1}
    }
        PLayGame(cellId,buSelected)

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

when you want to add onClick action to an element in the XML file by implementing onClickListener interface , in kotlin you can use Kotlin extensions for android also remember add it to the build.gradle file in you application as `apply plugin: kotlin-android-extensions` and then in your activity u can access to your element by its id and add the on `element_id.setOnClickListener{ onClickFunction()}`
and after that u can call your function like example or some thing else

Answer (score 0):

Look at your stack trace - it's organised into levels, where each level is an exception that was caused by the next exception. Each exception has a list of the method calls that led to the exception happening (the top one is the most recent):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:182)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.AutoPaly(MainActivity.kt:132)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.PLayGame(MainActivity.kt:55)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.AutoPaly(MainActivity.kt:149)
    at com.example.ticgame.MainActivity.PLayGame(MainActivity.kt:55)
    ...
```

The last exception is the important one, and if you read bottom to top, you can see the things that led to the exception. The last thing that happens is `PLayGame` calls `AutoPaly`, which calls `Random.nextInt`, and that call throws an exception with this message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
```

It's saying you called `Random.nextInt` with a value of `0`, and if that value is `<= 0` it throws an exception. Your code that's calling it (line 132 of `MainActivity.kt` according to the stack trace, it tells you where to look ;) ) is doing this:

```
var randIndex=r.nextInt(emptyCells.size)
```

So at some point, `emptyCells` can be empty with a size of `0`, and that's why it's crashing.